# Joining two Dask df

Tags: python, dataframe, inner-join, dask

I am trying to join two very big dask dataframes on an object column named patent_string.

I am doing this through the following command:

`dask_df1.join(dask_df2, on='patent_string',how='inner',lsuffix='left', rsuffix='right')`

after having convered the column "patent_string" for the two into an object type:

```
dask_df1['patent_string']=dask_df1['patent_string'].astype(object)
dask_df2['patent_string']=dask_df2['patent_string'].astype(object)
```

However, the following error appears when I try to join the 2:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [90], line 4
      1 ###OCCORRE RIMUOVERE I DUPLICATI IN STATA AD ESEMPIO:
      2 #df_emakg_cpc_y02y04 = vaex_df1.join(vaex_df2, how='inner', on='patent_string',lsuffix='left', rsuffix='right',allow_duplication=True)
----> 4 df_emakg_cpc_y02y04=dask_df1.join(dask_df2, on='patent_string',lsuffix='_caller', rsuffix='_other')

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/bocconi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py:5363, in DataFrame.join(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, npartitions, shuffle)
   5352         other = _recursive_pairwise_outer_join(
   5353             other,
   5354             on=on,
   (...)
   5358             shuffle=shuffle,
   5359         )
   5361 from dask.dataframe.multi import merge
-> 5363 return merge(
   5364     self,
   5365     other,
   5366     how=how,
   5367     left_index=on is None,
   5368     right_index=True,
   5369     left_on=on,
   5370     suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix),
   5371     npartitions=npartitions,
   5372     shuffle=shuffle,
   5373 )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/bocconi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/multi.py:607, in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, suffixes, indicator, npartitions, shuffle, max_branch, broadcast)
    605 left_empty = left._meta_nonempty
    606 right_empty = right._meta_nonempty
--> 607 meta = left_empty.merge(
    608     right_empty,
    609     how=how,
    610     on=on,
    611     left_on=left_on,
    612     right_on=right_on,
    613     left_index=left_index,
    614     right_index=right_index,
    615     suffixes=suffixes,
    616     indicator=indicator,
    617 )
    618 categorical_columns = meta.select_dtypes(include="category").columns
    620 if merge_indexed_left and left.known_divisions:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:9351, in DataFrame.merge(self, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
   9332 @Substitution("")
   9333 @Appender(_merge_doc, indents=2)
   9334 def merge(
   (...)
   9347     validate: str | None = None,
   9348 ) -> DataFrame:
   9349     from pandas.core.reshape.merge import merge
-> 9351     return merge(
   9352         self,
   9353         right,
   9354         how=how,
   9355         on=on,
   9356         left_on=left_on,
   9357         right_on=right_on,
   9358         left_index=left_index,
   9359         right_index=right_index,
   9360         sort=sort,
   9361         suffixes=suffixes,
   9362         copy=copy,
   9363         indicator=indicator,
   9364         validate=validate,
   9365     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py:107, in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     90 @Substitution("\nleft : DataFrame or named Series")
     91 @Appender(_merge_doc, indents=0)
     92 def merge(
   (...)
    105     validate: str | None = None,
    106 ) -> DataFrame:
--> 107     op = _MergeOperation(
    108         left,
    109         right,
    110         how=how,
    111         on=on,
    112         left_on=left_on,
    113         right_on=right_on,
    114         left_index=left_index,
    115         right_index=right_index,
    116         sort=sort,
    117         suffixes=suffixes,
    118         copy=copy,
    119         indicator=indicator,
    120         validate=validate,
    121     )
    122     return op.get_result()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py:704, in _MergeOperation.__init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    696 (
    697     self.left_join_keys,
    698     self.right_join_keys,
    699     self.join_names,
    700 ) = self._get_merge_keys()
    702 # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce
    703 # to avoid incompatible dtypes
--> 704 self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()
    706 # If argument passed to validate,
    707 # check if columns specified as unique
    708 # are in fact unique.
    709 if validate is not None:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py:1261, in _MergeOperation._maybe_coerce_merge_keys(self)
   1255     # unless we are merging non-string-like with string-like
   1256     elif (
   1257         inferred_left in string_types and inferred_right not in string_types
   1258     ) or (
   1259         inferred_right in string_types and inferred_left not in string_types
   1260     ):
-> 1261         raise ValueError(msg)
   1263 # datetimelikes must match exactly
   1264 elif needs_i8_conversion(lk.dtype) and not needs_i8_conversion(rk.dtype):

ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Maybe the object type is not the one I should adopt in dask?

EDIT:

I tried the following:

```
df_emakg_cpc_y02y04=dask_df1.set_index('patent_string').join(dask_df2.set_index('patent_string'))
```

but ended up with an empty dataframe!

EDIT2: This is my whole code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
dask_df1 = dd.from_pandas(df_emakg_cpc_green, npartitions=10)  # Dask DataFrame has 10 partitions
dask_df2 = dd.from_pandas(df_emakg, npartitions=10)

dask_df1['patent_string']=dask_df1['patent_string'].astype(str)
dask_df2['patent_string']=dask_df2['patent_string'].astype(str)

df_emakg_cpc_y02y04=dask_df1.join(dask_df2, on='patent_string',lsuffix='_caller', rsuffix='_other')
```

Unfortunately, I cannot provide you with an MWE since the dask dataframes are very long, and cannot figure out a way to provide you some representative data. The variable that I am trying to join on is an object type which I am trying to revert to a string type without success. Yet, while in dask_df2 the variable looks good, in dask_df1 it looks as in the picture (see right most variable):

[image]

Thank you

Comment: can you post all of your code, or a [mre]?

Comment: we can see your edit history - you can too by clicking on the `edited xx minutes ago` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73688944/revisions), so it's best to simply edit your question to be clear and include all relevant information rather than have a string of "edit" blocks. also, stack overflow asks that you [please don't post images of data, errors, or code when asking questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/) for a variety of reasons - instead, copy the result of `print(df)` into the question as a formatted code block. Thanks!

Comment: also can you post the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) (everything from `Traceback (most recent call last):` to the `ValueError` line) that is generated when you run your code example? it's full of valuable debugging information. make sure that you post the traceback which is generated when you run the exact code block in your question. thanks so much!